# Windows Store app - Grid app with different items

Tags: windows-8, grid

I have to do a Windows Store application in XAML and C#, and the "Grid app" template is almost exactly what I need...

The problem is that this template displays same items, divided in groups.

For my app, I would like to do exactly the same thing but for different type of items instead and have a different details page for each type of item...

This is my first app and I don't manage to do it... How can I do it easily ?

The new "Hub" control of Windows 8.1 would be really perfect, But I can't work with Visual studio 2013 and Windows 8.1... :

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

I had to use a TemplateSelector :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Migrating-apps-from-Windows-Phone-to-Windows-8/Custom-Styling-in-Windows-Store-Apps